# samsung galaxy tab 10.1 inch gt-p7500 android 3.2 google maps jquery lightbox z-index do not fit as on other devices

Tags: jquery, google-maps, lightbox, galaxy

When using samsung galaxy tab 10.1 inch gt-p7500 android 3.2 on Mozilla5.0 I have problem with google maps and jquery lightbox - I suppose that it is a problem with z-index - when you click on photo to see it in light box - the photo is under the dark layer which should cover all the page. It is issue with Google maps, becouse when on site there is no Google map - the light box work as it should

You can see following examples, this is working one (becouse site doesn't contain Google map):

http://wasthere.com/europe/en/i3/show-entry/19/mazurian-canal

And this is not working (becouse site cntains Google map):

http://wasthere.com/europe/en/i2/show-entry/149/gliwice-radio-station

Any one has some idea how to fix it?

On Opera everything is OK.

Comment: What is "Mozilla5.0"? Normally I would think that you mean Firefox - but Firefox 5.0 for Android is very outdated, I don't suppose you are testing with it. So you probably mean the user agent string - but "Mozilla 5.0" is common to the user agent string of all browsers for historical reasons. Are you talking about the built-in browser?

Comment: yes, I am talking about the default built-in browser. on Firefox it is OK.